# using mpirun -np in python script

Tags: python, bash, command-line, mpi

I want to run a pw.x in bash with this command: mpirun -np 4 pw.x < input.in through a python script. 
I used this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen( "mpirun -np 4 pw.x", shell=False, universal_newlines=True,
                  stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE )
output, error = process.communicate();
print (output);
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE )
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mpirun -np 4 pw.x': 'mpirun -np 4 pw.x'
```

How can I use "mpirun -np ..." in python scripts?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor: split your command and pass it as a list to `Popen`

Answer (score 1):

When you have `shell=False` in the `Popen` constructor, it expects the `cmd` to be a sequence; any type of `str` could be one but then the string is treated as the single element of the sequence -- this is happening in your case and the whole `mpirun -np 4 pw.x` string is being treated as the executable filename.

To solve this, you can:

- Use `shell=True` and keep everything else as-is, but beware of the security issues as this would be run directly in shell and you should not do this for any untrusted executable
- Use a proper sequence e.g. `list` for `cmd` in `Popen`:

  ```
  import shlex
  process = Popen(shlex.split("mpirun -np 4 pw.x"), shell=False, ...)
  ```

Both assuming `mpirun` exists in your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing

```
shell=False
```

to

```
shell=True
```

Answer (score 0):

With `shell=False`, you need to parse the command line into a list yourself.

Also, unless `subprocess.run()` is unsuitable for your needs, you should probably avoid calling `subprocess.Popen()` directly.

```
inp = open('input.in')
process = subprocess.run(['mpirun', '-np', '4', 'pw.x'],
    # Notice also the stdin= argument
    stdin=inp, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
    shell=False, universal_newlines=True)
inp.close()
print(process.stdout)
```

If you are stuck on an older Python version, maybe try `subprocess.check_output()`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess for why you want to avoid `shell=True`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but It doesn't work for me and doesn't show anything in output.